# Facebook og:image not scraping blog for images to use for thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, expressionengine

On a blog detail page I have Facebook OpenGraph tags pulling in various bits of data using the clients CMS tags etc. All works fine apart from the images.

Ideally, as the blog posts contain a lot of images, when posting an article to FB it should pull some of the images from the blog post to use as the thumbnail and let the client decide which one to use. If there are no images in the blog post then it falls back to the default thumbnail I've referenced in the 'og:image' tag. Am I correct in how this should operate?

Currently what happens is it only gives the option to use the default thumbnail and if I don't include the 'og:image' tag then it loads no thumbnail at all, instead of scraping the post for a blog image.

Has anyone encountered this before?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{title}"/>
{if facebook_description}
<meta property="og:description" content="{facebook_description}" />
{/if}
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.client.com/thumbnail.jpg"/>   
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{site_name}"/>   
<meta property="og:url" content="{page_url}/" />
```

Creating a separate field for a client to upload a specific thumb for every blog post seems overkill and the blog entries are all one textarea so I can't pull in a select image from the CMS.

Comment: _“Am I correct in how this should operate?”_ – no. When specifying an `og:image`, Facebook will use that – they will only look for images on the page itself if you haven’t specified one. But you can specify multiple `og:image`, so just do that … (although I think currently FB recognizes only the first three of those – if you specify more, they will get ignored.)

Comment: Thank you, this partly answers my question. However if I remove the og:image tag then it doesn't show any thumbnail even if there are images on the page.

Comment: Well, if you don’t/can’t specify what you want to be shown, then it ends up being a guessing game – in some cases the scraper is able to extract relevant images, in others it might not be … that can depend on many factors like HTML structure, etc.